# search direclty with body keypress in one column only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So whta i want to do is the next:

I have a table like this with draggable-sortable rows (using jquery ui sortable plugin)

```
id     name       author
------ ---------- ------------
1      cat-name   John
2      cat-name   John
3      cat-name   John
4      cat-name   John
```

In the table I have about 800 to 1000 rows and all I want is when I drag a row from postion 700 for example to 200 I typed directly 200 and the window go up to position number 200 (like a search but without input)

I tried this code

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d6vnpq5q/1/)

but it search in the entier page, I tried to change the window find to search only in td.index (search within first column only) only but it didn't work.

any ideas ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do exactly. You want to jump to a specific row in the table during when dragging an item to sort?

Comment: Some investigation has shown that event listening might get "paused" when items are being dragged. Still investigating and testing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/d6vnpq5q/4/

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632343/no-key-events-during-html5-drag-and-drop this suggests that only modifiers can be detected in drag. I tested with `SHIFT` and I can see in the event where `shiftKey` becomes `true`. I suspect you'd have to generate a landing spot that the item can be dragged to, and then the user can scroll to the proper location, and drag the item in.