# Javascript, DOM, detect keypresses while dragging an element

Tags: javascript, dom

I am currently making a wysiwyg editor, and need to support rotation by pressing "r" key while dragging some element with mouse

I noticed that onkeydown event is not being called when I try to press a key while dragging something with a mouse.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div draggable="true">Drag this and then try to press some keys</div>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    console.log(`Key pressed: ${event.key}`);
});

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    console.log(`Mouse button pressed: ${event.button}`);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the example code you can try on your own (make something draggable as well). So my question - is it even possible to do this in DOM or is it an unavoidable limitation?

Comment: I made a snippet of your code, as you can see you can press a key without problem while holding the mouse button. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkBaijens yes, I edited the initial version of the post, the problem only occurs while I am using a native HTML5 drag, so that would be the proper question

Comment: Then I suggest editing your question so the code reproduces your problem. Why can't tell where you went wrong if you don't show what you did.

Comment: @MarkBaijens added the full html snippet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678871/1427878 suggests that what you want, might simply not be possible.